# ANTLR4 (C#) - Error

Tags: c#, antlr4, typeconverter

I´m new to ANTLR and using ANTLR4 on Visual Studio 2010.

I have the following 'Example.g4':

```
grammar Example;

options
{
    language=CSharp3;
    TokenLabelType=CommonToken;
    output=AST;
    ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}

example : op=MULT;

MULT: '*' ;
WS : [ \t\n]+ -> skip ;
```

When I try to compile, I get the following error message:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'Antlr4.Runtime.IToken' to 'Antlr4.Runtime.CommonToken'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) xxx\obj\x86\Debug\ExampleParser.cs  74  30

The line 74 is:

```
State = 2; _localctx.op = Match(MULT);
```

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I had a a **TokenLabelType=CommonToken;** in my **options{}**. When I took it off, the error was gone.

Comment: You need to remove that entire `options` block. None of those options are valid in ANTLR 4.